# Customising Honeycomb email notification to a presentable format

Tags: android-3.0-honeycomb, email-notifications, alerts

I find email notifications to be poor from Honeycomb, is there a way I can apply custom template to make the email more presentable when retrieving notifications?

such as listing the **service name** that have **error** in the last 5 minutes to a table format?

I cannot find anything such in the documentation, but for Android (*which I am not after that*)